Пустое значение update_time в информации о таблице
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM bd LIKE 'news'

Не понимаю, ранее Update_time имело значение. Содержало временную метку последнего изменения.
А сейчас она пуста...
Перезапускал mysql через консоль, но после перезапуска в таблицу вносились изменения, а метка пуста...
Запрос о другой таблице, содержит update_time

В таблицах делал перемещение полей, быть может из-за этого перестало выдавать значение поля?

Хотя вносил после этого изменения и все равно пустое...

Не понимаю, что происходит, около часа не было значение, а сейчас оно есть. Куда пропадало на время?

Какой великий смысл в этом значении? Содержало временную метку последнего изменения. Нет. Это метка времени последнего обновления файла, в котором хранятся данные таблицы, на диске. И с штампом времени последней модификации оно соотносится весьма слабо. А пустое значение говорит о том, что либо сервер не смог получить этот штамп по какой-то причине, либо данные таблицы хранятся в более чем одном файле. Если действительно необходим штамп времени последнего изменения - добавляете autoutilized timestamp column, либо создаёте триггер, который пишет этот штамп времени в служебную таблицу.

Не совсем понял про autoutilized timestamp column, это в таблице будет дополнительное поле у каждой записи? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Если таблица создана, как добавить свое доп.поле в информацию о таблице в которой будет метка последней правки в таблице. Или опять неверно понял, в любом случаи если речь идет о дополнительном поле в таблице, которое добавит доп.ячейку к каждой записи - это не выход

Дополнительное поле о информации о таблице, а не поле в самой таблице. Верно?

В случае автополя - да, в каждой записи будет штамп времени последнего изменения именно этой записи. И соответственно максимальное по таблице значение этого поля будет штампом времени последнего изменения в таблице вообще. А в случае набора триггеров - создаётся дополнительная таблица, в которую триггеры пишут только штамп времени последнего изменяющего действия на всей таблице, безотносительно к тому, какая запись изменена, ну и имя таблицы, если регистрируем штамп времени изменения для нескольких таблиц.
